# How to use blackbody node in compositor?

Tags: compositing-nodes, color

How to use blackbody node in compositor? It is in [Cycles shader nodes](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/shader_nodes/converter/blackbody.html):

[image: blackbody node]

Searching for "blackbody" in compositor has no results.

Comment: Hi :). I don't think there's a blackbody node in the Compositor. Shader nodes and Compositor nodes are two different systems.